# iOS Math for a turret/cannon that rotates to follow a finger

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiview, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out the math for rotating a UIView a certain side is always "follows" a finger when moving on the screen.

I'm almost there but I haven't had trigonometry in years and I can't figure out exactly what to do. Here is what I've got:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    int dy = cannon.frame.origin.y - touchPoint.y;
    int dx = cannon.frame.origin.x - touchPoint.x;

    cannon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2(dy,dx) - 135);
}
```

Comment: If this helps, Ray Wenderlich wrote about rotating turrets.  It's in cocos2d, but I think there are quite a few parallels in plain old objc: http://www.raywenderlich.com/692/rotating-turrets

Comment: How is your current solution differing from what you want to happen? `atan2` is the easiest thing to use for instant tracking so you look like you've pretty much got it figured out.

Comment: It's not quite following it right. It spazzes out in some spots, and when I keep the X value constant and move the Y up and down, it moves the UIView too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thank you to everyone who took the time to answer!

I played around with it for a while, and it seems that the only problem was that I used `int`s for `dy` and `dx` instead of `float`s. I also found a nifty, quick "method" for converting degrees to radians. Here is the final, working code:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    float dy = cannon.frame.origin.y - touchPoint.y;
    float dx = cannon.frame.origin.x - touchPoint.x;

    cannon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2(dy,dx) - DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your turret initial heading is right.

Your PI constant is 3.14 (angles in radian)

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    int dy = cannon.frame.origin.y - touchPoint.y;
    int dx = cannon.frame.origin.x - touchPoint.x;

    float a = atan(abs(dy)/abs(dx));
    if(dx>0 && dy<0) a += PI/2;
    if(dx<0 && dy<0) a += PI;
    if(dx<0 && dy>0) a += 3*PI/2;

    cannon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(a);
}
```

I think it could be more optimized (no if), but I can't test myself for the moment. Does it works ?

Comment: This is just reimplementing `atan2` poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Your constant 135 is probably incorrect, as `atan2` and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` both work in radians, not degrees. The radian equivalent of 135 degrees is π·3/4.

However, other than that, your code looks fine — this should just cause a constant offset, not the odd behavior you describe. Are you sure that `cannon.frame.origin` is not itself affected by the transformation?